# OpenRewrite: AddCommentToMavenDependencymaven recipe not working with given POM

Tags: openrewrite

I am trying to use `AddCommentToMavenDependency` recipe to add a comment line inside a dependency declaration. But I think I am not able to provide the correct xpath, please correct.

```
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.maven.AddCommentToMavenDependency:
      xPath: /project/dependencies/dependency
      groupId: com.myorg.exe
      artifactId: exe-starter-parent
      commentText: This is excluded due to CVE <X> and will be removed when we upgrade the next version is available.
```

Below is pom.xml

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myorg.exe</groupId>
        <artifactId>exe-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.24</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myorg.exe.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>gooseberry-webclient-rest</artifactId>
    <version>${app_version}</version>
    <name>gooseberry-webclient-rest</name>
    <description>A sample project demonstrating the service kernel usage for a REST API Server</description>
    <properties>
        <snakeyaml.version>2.0</snakeyaml.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AddCommentToMavenDependency](https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/maven/addcommenttomavendependency) adds a comment to a Maven dependency; in your example I don't see a Maven dependency matching the parameters that you've added. You might want to look at this example taken from the tests.

https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/blob/c54d9ca209ab78589f86e8685e3ffc50f7eb8348/rewrite-maven/src/test/java/org/openrewrite/maven/AddCommentToMavenDependencyTest.java#L68C31-L74